# What is the status of the javascript target for antlr3

Tags: javascript, antlr

What ist the current status of the Javascript target in antlr3? I tried to generate a parser for a simple grammar but the generated code contains lots of compiler errors. After checking the website I checked out the current antlr3.5-snapshot code and built antlr from the source with maven. The results are still the same? Is there some special version that I can use? Or is the target broken? (I found comments about the target being broken in 3.1, 3.2, working in 3.3 and nothing about 3.4 and 3.5)
Hier is an example for the Javascript code that doesn't work:

```
// public class variables
var = ,
    = ,
    = ,
...
    = ,
    = ;
```

There is more of this kind of code in the generated lexer and parser files.

Any hints are greatly appreciated.

This is the very simple test grammar I used to try out javascript code generation. Almost everything was generated by antlrworks. I added the target language and the prog rule. (Please don't spend too much time editing this grammar to make it work. Antlrworks checked the grammar and the Java code generation works. So - from a user point of view - Javascript code generation should work without changing the grammar.) 
Thanks again for your help.

```
grammar TestgrammarV001;

options {
language=JavaScript;
}


prog    :    ID | INT;

ID  :   ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'_')*
    ;

INT :   '0'..'9'+
    ;

FLOAT
    :   ('0'..'9')+ '.' ('0'..'9')* EXPONENT?
    |   '.' ('0'..'9')+ EXPONENT?
    |   ('0'..'9')+ EXPONENT
    ;

COMMENT
    :   '//' ~('\n'|'\r')* '\r'? '\n' {$channel=HIDDEN;}
    |   '/*' ( options {greedy=false;} : . )* '*/' {$channel=HIDDEN;}
    ;

WS  :   ( ' '
        | '\t'
        | '\r'
        | '\n'
        ) {$channel=HIDDEN;}
    ;

STRING
    :  '"' ( ESC_SEQ | ~('\\'|'"') )* '"'
    ;

CHAR:  '\'' ( ESC_SEQ | ~('\''|'\\') ) '\''
    ;

fragment
EXPONENT : ('e'|'E') ('+'|'-')? ('0'..'9')+ ;

fragment
HEX_DIGIT : ('0'..'9'|'a'..'f'|'A'..'F') ;

fragment
ESC_SEQ
    :   '\\' ('b'|'t'|'n'|'f'|'r'|'\"'|'\''|'\\')
    |   UNICODE_ESC
    |   OCTAL_ESC
    ;

fragment
OCTAL_ESC
    :   '\\' ('0'..'3') ('0'..'7') ('0'..'7')
    |   '\\' ('0'..'7') ('0'..'7')
    |   '\\' ('0'..'7')
    ;

fragment
UNICODE_ESC
    :   '\\' 'u' HEX_DIGIT HEX_DIGIT HEX_DIGIT HEX_DIGIT
    ;
```

Comment: Err, you're compiling a JS-generated parser? I assume you mean "running" instead of "compiling"? The JS code you posted, is that part of the generated parser/lexer code? Can you post the grammar?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You're right I should have been more precise. The error messages come from the syntax checker of Aptana (ecliopse based Javascript IDE). The grammar I used is very simple. I took the defaults that are generated bei Antlrworks when it creates a new grammar. I added a single rule:
prog :  ID | INT;

Comment: I also added language=Javascript (of course :-)). The syntax errors are from the generated Javascript code. The generated code seems to be generated by a template that tries to iterate over tokens. I tried to add a tokens section to the grammar file but that did not change anything.

Comment: I am not aware of a fixed amount of default rules ANTLRWorks generates (I know it can generate different rules, but then the question would be which ones you choose). So, can you edit your question and simply post the grammar that causes this error, simple as it may be?

Answer (score 0):

I posted a similar question about a year and a half ago (here's the post: [Status of Javascript in antlr 3.4 or 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19841084/status-of-javascript-in-antlr-3-4-or-3-5/19844367?noredirect=1#comment30319387_19844367)).

The JavaScript target works in ANTLR v3.3 but not 3.4 or 3.5.

Comment: Oops! I didn't see the date on this post.